# Typescript using typeof with a key selected from keyof

Tags: typescript, knex.js

Using a package called "typed-knex" for a commercial project, its got smart type restrictions in its functions. For example, when constructing a query, by specifying the table type, it restricts field names to only valid names. I've discovered that this is thanks to `keyof T` that affectively returns an array of possible strings given type T.

It takes this one step further by also restricting the type of another param based on the previously entered "keyof T".

For example, given the table

```
export class PriceTable {
  created: Date | null;
  retail_price: number | null;
}
```

when calling `typedKnex.query(PriceTable).where('created', '>=', X)`, it requires X to be a Date type. and when calling `typedKnex.query(PriceTable).where('retail_price', '>=', X)` it requires X to be a number.

I'm trying to recreate this functionality to better understand how it works, so far I've got

```
  function addFiltersToQuery<T>(mappings: { [queryKey: string]: { columnName: keyof T, op?: string, transformFn: (val: any) => any } }) { }
```

I've got the `keyof T` part down for restricting `columnName`, but haven't figured out what I need to change `transformFn: (val: any) => *any*` part to. I'd want to say `typeof(keyof T)` but I need to get the `keyof T` they chose for "columnName" and get the type of that.

I have tried looking at the typedefs for `typed-knex` itself but they are very complicated and seem to do a lot more than what I'm after. So I'm hoping someone can explain just the part I'm missing or what I'd need to do to get that information.

Comment: * `keyof` operator returns a union of keys, not a tuple type (just an off-note)

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/mL922W) what you're looking for?  I don't know if the `(val: any) => any` part needs to do something to both `any`s (`anies`?) or just the return type.  If it works for you I can write up an answer; if not, please elaborate on what you're looking for by editing the question.

Comment: "I'd want to say typeof(keyof T)" you can write that as `T[keyof T]`, or `T[K]` for a specific key. "but I need to get the keyof T they chose for "columnName" and get the type of that." so this is inherently going to be somewhat complicated because `T[keyof T]` isn't good enough.  We need to match specific keys to specific values.  You either need to use a generic key `K` or use a mapped type to pair the keys to their options, which is what @jcalz has done.

Comment: There's a fairly straightforward way to do this with a dummy conditional to distribute over the key union: https://tsplay.dev/mA7rPw